# Duplicate values in a single row in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

```
df <- data.frame(label = c("a","b","c"),
                 val=c("x","b","c"),
                 val1=c("z","b","d"))

   label val val1
1     a   x    z
2     b   b    b
3     c   c    d
```

I want find out the duplicate values in each row. 
 for 1st row, there is no duplicate
 for 2nd row , "b" is duplicate
 for 3rd row, "c" is duplicate.
How to find this duplicate in R programming.

Also I need to replace the duplicate elements with `NA` value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `duplicated` with `apply`

```
apply(df,1,duplicated)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

And replace it with `NA`

```
df[t(apply(df,1,duplicated))]=NA
df
  label  val val1
1     a    x    z
2     b <NA> <NA>
3     c <NA>    d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of options

Using base R `apply` we `replace` the `duplicated` values to `NA` for each row

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))

df
#  label  val val1
#1     a    x    z
#2     b <NA> <NA>
#3     c <NA>    d
```

---

Or another alternative using `dplyr` and `tidyr` is to first create a new column representing the `row_number()` of the dataframe, `gather` it to long format, `group_by` each row, `replace` `duplicated` value to `NA` and `spread` it back into wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, duplicated(value), NA)) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  label val   val1 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     x     z    
#2 b     NA    NA   
#3 c     NA    d
```